# Join table in rails; many-to-many; trying to call join method on instance

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, has-many-through

I just did this a few hours ago and now I can't getting it working on a second attempt.  There are many Users and many EventGoals. Users have many EventGoals and EventGoals have many Users, both through the join table called EventGoalClaims.  The @event_goal is getting passed properly but I get a `

```
undefined method `event_goal_claims' for #<EventGoal:0x007fd11b0ce178>`
```

Here's the view (the first line is hitting an error):

```
<%= form_for([@event_goal, @event_goal.event_goal_claims.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value =>  current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_last_name, :value =>  current_user.last_name %>
```

Controller

```
  def create
        @event_goal = EventGoal.find(params[:event_goal_id])
        @event_goal_claim = @event_goal.event_goal_claims.build(eventgoalclaim_params)
          @event_goal_claim.event_goal_id = @event_goal.id
          @event_goal_claim.user_id = current_user.id
          @event_goal_claim.user_last_name = current_user.last_name

...

 private
  def eventgoalclaim_params
    params.require(:event_goal_claim).permit(:event_goal_id, :user_id, :user_last_name, :approved)
  end
```

EDIT

```
class EventGoal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
    has_many :users, through: :event_goal_claims
end
```

Comment: Can you paste your event_goal.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer likely lies in the associations of one of the three respective models.  Make sure they look like this:

```
user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_goal_claims
  has_many :event_goals, through: :event_goal_claims

event_goal.rb
Class EventGoal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_goal_claims
  has_many :users, through: :event_goal_claims

event_goal_claim.rb
Class EventGoalClaim < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event_goal
```

Also worth noting:  This is all assuming your db has the foreign keys on the `event_goal_claims table` in your `schema.rb` labeled as `user_id and event_goal_id`.  If they are different than that, you will need to explicitly state the name of the foreign key in the model's associations.